# How I can synchronize entities with database in Jdeveloper 12c?

Tags: jpa, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I've searched in ggl and found examples for Jdeveloper 11, and you can right-click on entities and press "synchronize", but in Jdeveloper 12c I can't see this option, I need to configure something or there's another way to do this in 12c?

Comment: and the relevance of JPA API to this?

Comment: I don't see it wither and see no mention in the JDev docs. It's possible support for this was removed in this release. Can you switch to NetBeans? It has better tooling support for JPA than JDev (IMHO). JDev has better tooling for ADF BC.

Comment: @Neil Stockton I don't understand what do you mean, I'm using JPA anotations in my entities

Comment: @Joe I'm using Jdev because it helps me to create "oracle-friendly screens" easily and fast so I can integrate it in other weblogic apps

Comment: So you're using JPA annotations, and? What relevance do they have to some option in your IDE? The JPA API is not called.

Comment: By "Oracle Friendly Screens" I assume you mean ADF Faces? You can build your JPA in netbeans easier & then use JDev to create Data Controls based on the JPA/Session Beans and then D&D onto ADF Faces pages. If I do jpa in JDev, then I usually have to gen new JPA entities and copy code to the existing ones- not very nice tooling, which is why I prefer NB for JPA. But Data control support in JDev is quite good.

Comment: @Joe thanks for your reply, it was useful, for now I will try to use only JDev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about Oracle ADF Business Components Entity Objects - than the synchronization menu option is still there in 12.
JDeveloper never had a synchronize with DB option for JPA entities.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySql then you will not get **Synchronize with database option**.